# NGINX RTMP stream with Hamachi

Tags: nginx, rtmp, hamachi

In summary, I builded a NGINX server on my Raspberry PI 4 to stream to my cousin when we are doing a multiStream on Twitch (Did this because I found nothing free that can stream 1080p60). In others terms, I stream to him via RTMP and he get my RTMP stream to put on his OBS which stream on Twitch.

We have 3 PCs on the Hamachi server : Mine, the Raspi and my cousin's PC (Only the Raspi and my PC are on the same non-hamachi network).

The problem is that my cousin cannot connect to my RTMP stream, nor stream on it. He have access to my Apache website and my samba share, but not the RTMP stream.

On my side, the stream work, whenever I access it with the hostname of the pi or with its Hamachi IP.

We disabled our Windows Firewall, I added "allow play all" on my rtmp.conf... but nothing work. I also thought that the problem would be the fact that my cousin didn't have ffmpeg, but I tested a stream on my laptop on Xubuntu and it's work (I checked and my laptop didn't have ffmpeg). I just don't know if it is a Hamachi restriction or if I miss something on NGINX.

Anyways, here my files (I just want to note that my file sites-enabled/default is deleted because NGINX was conflicting with my Apache)

rtmp.conf

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            allow play all;
        } 
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/rtmp.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you run a short `tcpdump port 1935` on the pi, do you see the rtmp traffic you expect? This should help rule out whether the issue is on your end or his.